# Path on spring form select not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am having an issue getting the jsp to render properly. The path on my select tag seems to be the culprit, but I cannot track don't why.

I get the error: Error 500: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute

And my code is:

Controller.java

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("view")
@SessionAttributes({"analyticFormBean"})
public class RolesAnalyticsController {
@RenderMapping
public String defaultRenderer(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, ModelMap map){
    logger.entering(SOURCE_CLASS, "defaultRenderer");
    request.setAttribute("reportList", getReportList());
    logger.exiting(SOURCE_CLASS, "defaultRenderer", VIEW_JSP);
    return VIEW_JSP;
}
```

View.jsp

```
<form:form id="reportForm" method="POST" action="${submitReportQuery}">

<form:select path="query" id="reportSelection" onchange="javascript:checkForFields()">
    <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---"/>
    <form:options items="${reportList}" />
</form:select>

&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" ><br>

<div class="fieldPlaceholder" id="fieldPlaceholder"></div>
```

Bean.java

```
public class AnalyticFormBean {
    private int reportID;
    private String query;
    private String queryResult;
    private String[] listOfQueries;
```

Comment: Is that the entire controller?  You need to actually put the AnalyticFormBean into the modelmap at some point.

Comment: Yes it is. Do I have to do: map.addAttribute(bean); ?

Comment: map.addAttribute("analyticFormBean", bean) if you want your @SessionAttributes to do anything.

Comment: I added the following but that still didn't help. 
AnalyticFormBean bean = new AnalyticFormBean();
bean.setListOfQueries(new String[]{});
bean.setQuery("");
bean.setReportID(0);
bean.setQueryResult("");
map.addAttribute("analyticFormBean", bean);

Comment: form:form tag needs commandName="analyticFormBean"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing two things,

- the backing bean has to be actually added to the ModelMap at some point, so you need a `map.addAttribute("analyticFormBean", new AnalyticFormBean())` (or with whatever initial values you want added to it, etc.)
- You have to tell the form tag the name of the backing object `<form:form commandName="analyticFormBean" etc>`

Answer (score 0):

I dont see you using the bean in the form... you need to add it to the form.

```
<form:form commandName="analyticFormBean" .......>
```